# Article with dates necessary?

Tags: grammar, article, time

> Ich arbeite hier zwischen 01. Februar und 15. März.
>
> Ich bleibe hier bis 22. April.
>
> Ich bin von 05. bis 12. Mai in Mailand.

Do these sentences need articles for dates, or are they fine as they are?

Comment: I think the leading 0 should be omitted here, i.e., "1. Februar" instead of "01. Februar".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, with days and month you'd need to use an article. So it would be:

> Ich arbeite hier zwischen **dem** 01. Februar und **dem** 15. März.
>
> Ich bleibe hier bis **zum** 22. April.
>
> Ich bin **vom** 05. bis **zum** 12. Mai in Mailand.

But not with times:

> Ich arbeite zwischen 6:00 und 17:00 Uhr.
>
> Ich bleibe bis 22:00 Uhr hier.
>
> Ich bin von 05:00 bis 12:00 zu Hause.

You can find an overview of the use of the different [temporal prepositions here](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=87)

Comment: You (can) use articles with dates because the names of the 12 months have articles (they are all masculine).

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I would use articles.

> Ich arbeite hier zwischen **dem** 01. Februar und **dem** 15. März.
>
> Ich bleibe hier bis **zum** 22. April.
>
> Ich bin **vom** 05. bis **zum** 12. Mai in Mailand.

The first sentence could work without articles, if you read it as 01. = "erstem" und 15. = "fünfzehntem".

Keep in mind, that I don't know if there is any rule, it just *sounds* right for me.

Comment: In the first sentence, I would repeat "dem": "zwischem dem 1. Feb und dem 15. Mar". I don't think that it ever works without an article (for these examples; there might be some use cases where you can drop them, but I can't think of any right now).

Comment: you are right, I revised my answer. also thanks for correcting my typo :)